# Why does python give FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error even though the file exists?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning

I am trying to make a machine learning model and use django rest framework to connect it.
My folder structure is like this

```
server
|
+-- chat
|    |
|    +-- DistilBertModel
|    |    |
|    |    +-- OurModel
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    +-- BERT_model.py
|    |    |    +-- chatbot.py
|    |    |    +-- chatbot_predict.py
|    |    |    +-- model.sav
|    |    +-- data
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    +-- test_chatbot.csv
|    |    |    +-- answers.json
|    +-- migrations
|    +-- __init__.py
|    +-- admin.py
|    +-- apps.py
|    +-- models.py
|    +-- serializers.py
|    +-- tests.py
|    +-- urls.py
|    +-- views.py
+-- core
|
+-- templates
|
+-- db.sqlite3
|
+-- manage.py
|
+-- requirements.txt
```

In **chatbot_predict.py** file I am trying to load the model and get a prediction using that model. The code is like this

```
import joblib
loaded_model = joblib.load ('model.sav')

def get_prediction (message, loaded_model = loaded_model):
    return prediction
```

When I run this file using **python chatbot_predict.py** using command line it works fine.
However when I import this *get_prediction* function in **server/chat/views.py** and run **python manage.py runserver** it gives the error
[image]

What am I doing wrong to get that FileNotFoundError ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the absolute path of model.sav?

Comment: Yeah I tried with absolute path as well, but same issues

Answer (score 0):

This is because the file is now in a different location than the python script file or the current directory. 
Try providing full path of the model file (not just name) and it should work in both the cases.

Ideally you should invoke all your scripts in the root directory of your project (which becomes working directory) and accordingly provide file paths, to load, relative to the root directory.